# What's the OpenWhisk way to keep an auth token alive?

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk

So, I am dealing with a system where I need to be keeping an auth token alive by periodically (essentially daily) renewing the token and giving it to the functions that need it.

The way I would do this in plain old node.js is I would just use a SetInterval timer to renew it.

should I approach this the same way with an OpenWhisk action? I can build into the action it's work SetInterval and keep the token up to date. Or I could imagine creating an action which took input from an interval trigger as well as regular requests and have the action update on trigger requests and return the token on other requests. Or should I be using cloudant as the backend to manage the token?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The following approach might solve your issue

1. write one action (A) that renews the token
2. call action A at the beginning of any other action by using the action sequence capability [Creating action sequences](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_actions.html#openwhisk_create_action_sequence)
3. use the alarms (cron) trigger service to run action A periodically in order to renew the token even if your sequence is not executed [Using the Alarms package](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_alarms.html#openwhisk_catalog_alarm)
4. in case you need to store the token in action A you might think about using cloudant